# How can I pass group information to a time-series Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have time series data for around 5 people that I'm using to classify the next value with. I've windowed the datasets for each and it results in a couple thousand samples. I'd like to try to create a "general" model instead of individualized models by training a model on 4 out of the 5 people's data and using the 5th as a holdout set. My training data would be the 4 people's data stacked by rows. For example,

```
train_data1.shape = (2543, 6, 1)
train_data2.shape = (6002, 6, 1)
train_data3.shape = (4034, 6, 1)
train_data4.shape = (7834, 6, 1)

train_data = np.vstack([train_data1, train_data2, train_data3, train_data4])
train_data.shape = (20413, 6, 1)
```

My model is built from Tensorflow like

```
import tensorflow as tf

class FunctionalLSTM(Model):
    def __init__(self, timesteps, input_dim, lstm_dim):
        super(FunctionalLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.timesteps = timesteps
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.lstm_dim  = lstm_dim
        
        self.lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(self.lstm_dim, input_shape=(self.timesteps, self.input_dim),
                                          return_sequences=True)
        self.lstm2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(int(self.lstm_dim/2), return_sequences = False)
        
        self.predictions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid', name = 'predictions')
        
    def call(self, x):
        x = self.lstm1(x)
        x = self.lstm2(x)
        x = self.predictions(x)
        return x
    
    def build_graph(self):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.timesteps, self.input_dim),)
        return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))
```

In a random mixed effects model, I'd pass ID's to tell the model to count the people the dataset came from as a random effect. Is this necessary to do for this time series model when I'm combining people's data, and if so, how can I implement that in Tensorflow?